# in arr_homepage array contain title of array how set table view cell in swift 3

Tags: ios, arrays, swift, swift3, tableview

```
print(self.baseClass.response!.homepage![0])
```

Hi,

Want to access `home_page` that contain array of title string.
I want title string array for accessing in `tableview` cell.

Please help me to fix the issue.

Comment: post some code about the string in base class and some code you used to in tablviewcell

Comment: public class func modelsFromDictionaryArray(array:NSArray) -> [Json4Swift_Base]
    {
        var models:[Json4Swift_Base] = []
        for item in array
        {
            models.append(Json4Swift_Base(dictionary: item as! NSDictionary)!)
        }
        return models
    }
required public init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {

  if (dictionary["response"] != nil) { response = Response(dictionary: dictionary["response"] as! NSDictionary) }
 }    // HomeArrayClass

Comment: //homearr class  required public init?(dictionary: NSDictionary) {

  heading = dictionary["heading"] as? String
  oredr_by = dictionary["oredr_by"] as? String
  title = dictionary["title"] as? String
  if (dictionary["products"] != nil) { products = Products.modelsFromDictionaryArray(array: dictionary["products"] as! NSArray) }
 }

Comment: post it in question